# including multiple related classes without looping includes

Tags: c++, linker, include, c++20

I have a problem with linking multiple headers with classes that depend on each other:

- in *Entity.hpp* I have **Entity** class
- in *Manager.hpp* I have **Manager** class
- in *Scene.hpp* I have **Scene** class

**Scene** stores **Manager** which stores multiple **Entity** instances, but:

**Entity** class has a pointer to **Scene** where it is stored (using **Manager**)

*Entity.hpp*:

```
#include "Scene.hpp"

class Entity
{
public:

    Entity(Scene* scene_ref);
    Entity(const Entity& other);
    ~Entity();

    entityID ID() const; // example of normal function (defined in .cpp file)

    template <typename ComponentType, typename... Args>
    void addComponent(Args&&... args); // example of template function


private:

    Scene* m_scene_ref;
    entityID m_ID;
};


template <typename ComponentType, typename ...Args>
inline void Entity::addComponent(Args&& ...args) // definition of template function
{
    m_scene_ref->component_registry.add<ComponentType>(m_ID, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

*Manager.hpp*:

```
#include "Entity.hpp"


class Manager
{
public:

    Manager();
    ~Manager();

    void add(Entity&& entity);
    void add(const std::string& name, Entity&& entity);

private:

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Entity>> m_named_entities;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> m_entities;

    Scene* m_scene_ref;
};
```

*Scene.hpp*:

```
class Manager; // forward declaration of Manager

class Scene
{
public:
    
    // constructors, methods etc...

private:

    Manager entity_manager;
};
```

Without **Manager** class, everything is links fine. When I try to run this, VS throws error: `Error C2079 'Scene::entity_manager' uses undefined class 'Manager'`

I cannot figure out how to properly include these files so they don't produce linking errors (mainly because of linking loops). Also, pre-defining classes does not solve the issue.

And of course, is this code 'legal' or I am doing everything wrong?

Thank you for all your answers

**SOLUTION:
I solved it by putting everything from Entity.hpp to Scene.hpp, under the Scene class**

Comment: Have you tried forward declaring some classes? That is the solution to this problem. You may also have to move some code around so methods are defined after all the classes are fully defined.

Comment: @john yes, I tried doing some forward declarations (in many different combinations) but I failed every time. Also, I keep my methods in .cpp file and templates as inline under class definitions.

Comment: Templates possibly changes things, but without specific details it's hard to help. There is no other solution than forward declarations (or redesigning the classes). Sometimes it helps in a practical way, to forget about the separate header files. See if you can write a single header file declaring all three classes.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and the full compiler error you encountered

Comment: You might have to split the header into the class declaration and template method definitions. Then you can include all the class declarations before the template method definitions. Anything that requires more than a forward declaration of the other classes move into the second header file.

Comment: Getting into these sorts of loops is usually an indicator of a poor design but ignoring that could you just make `entity_manager` a `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles unfortunately it does not work too